# Where is the option to add online accounts listed? It certainly isn't under settings in my system!

Tags: settings, system

[image]

No option to add online accounts under system settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Online accounts hasn't been released into stable yet. You won't have it on a clean install. It's still in development.

Answer (score 1):

It *should* be right there next to the Network icon:

[image: system settings in elementary OS Freya]

First of all, verify that you have appropriate packages installed. You might have accidentally removed some of them. Here's the list of packages you need:

[image: the list of online accounts packages]

The most important one is the first one (`libpantheon-online-accounts0`) so you could try fixing this error by typing:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libpantheon-online-accounts0
```

If that doesn't work, you should try running `switchboard` from the terminal and see if you'll get any errors when executing it. If so, please update your question and post the errors you're getting and I'll do my best to see what went wrong.